# How to assign colours to geom points according to range

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe named `locs`. `head(locs)` is:

```
      Long      Lat variable1
1 71.61990 33.94370        13
2 71.74278 34.14943        13
3 72.00248 34.00935        52
4 72.03998 34.20004        11
5 72.47015 34.12015        12
6 71.43268 33.60269         0
```

How can I create a range of `variable1`? And furthermore how can I assign `colors` according to the range?

The code I have tried:

```
base_world +
  geom_point(data=locs, 
             aes(x=Long, y=Lat), colour="Deep Pink", 
             fill="Pink",pch=21, size=3, alpha=I(0.7))
```

In reality my dataframe `locs` has 123 observations

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by range? Perhaps `cut()` is the function you need. Create a new variable with this than map it with `aes(color=new_var)`.

Comment: I want to convert variable1 into range  e.g 0-9, 10-19 etc. and assign them different colours accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut()` to divide your variable in ranges, defined by you.

```
locs$new_var <- cut(locs$variable1, breaks=c(0, 9, 19), labels=c(0-9, 9-19, 19+))
```

Once you have created a new variable use it for the color `aes()`:

```
ggplot(locs, aes(x=Long,y=Lat,color=new_var)) + # or fill=new_var
    geom_point()
```